# How to Wait for Dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm using react and flux utils, with es6. I'd like the `SalesStore` to wait for the `SessionStore` to finish before executing its own dispatch. In the `SalesStore` I have the following, but the dispatch does not wait. Does anyone know what the issue could be? Thanks.

```
class SalesStore extends ReduceStore {

    getInitialState() {
        return {};
    }

    reduce(state, action) {
        switch(action.type) {
            case Constants.FETCH_SALES:
                this.getDispatcher().waitFor([SessionStore.getDispatchToken()]);
                return state;

            case Constants.FETCH_SALES_SUCCESS:                
                this.getDispatcher().waitFor([SessionStore.getDispatchToken()]);
                return action.payload;

            case Constants.FETCH_SALES_FAILURE:
                this.getDispatcher().waitFor([SessionStore.getDispatchToken()]);
                return state;

            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

}

export default new SalesStore(AppDispatcher);
```

Answer (score -1):

The reducer must be pure function
so you should move async calls to action creators

```
function getToken(){
   // Async call then
   return {
     type:'GET_TOKEN_SUCCESS' 
   }
}

function getSales(){
   // async then
   return {
     type:'GET_SALES_SUCCESS' 
   }
}

// main action will call `getToken` and `fetchSales` actions
function fetchSales(params){
    return dispatch => {
         dispatch(getToken()).then((res)=> dispatch(getSales())
    }
}
```

To manage promises you can use this [middleware](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/redux/middleware/clientMiddleware.js)